# Can I get tagged users in a public post through Facebook api?

Tags: facebook-sdk-4.0

I can get the post id, get post details (number of likes, comments, message, photo attachment etc.), but I can't seem to find a way to get the list of facebook users who got tagged into that post. Is it posible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the post Id and then pass this to the post to get the list of tags:
post_id?fields=with_tags

Comment: I tried but it said (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (with_tags) on node type (Status). I'm using v2.3

Comment: When I use user_id/posts?fields=with_tags I get for example

{
  "data": [
    {
      "with_tags": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "tagged_user_id_xxyyzzzxxxx", 
            "name": "John Smith"
          }
        ]
      }, 
      "id": "post_id_xxxyyyxxxxxy", 
      "created_time": "timestamp_of_post"
    }, 
    {
      "with_tags": {
        "data": [ ...
and so on...